# Что на самом деле значит SO_REUSEADDR?

Tags: c, сокет, unix

Здравствуйте, уже не первый раз натыкаюсь на опцию сокета SO_REUSEADDR, вот кусок из книги "UNIX. профессиональное программирование":
Как правило, реализация протокола TCP не допускает присваивать тот же самый адрес другому сокету, пока не пройдет определенный  промежуток  времени,  который  обычно  составляет  несколько  минут. К счастью, это ограничение легко обойти с помощью параметра SO_REUSEADDR...

и подобным образом нигде не объясняется суть: а что значит "переиспользование"? Это значит, что в определенный момент несколько процессов могут слушать, например localhost:80 т.е. один сокет? или этот сокет нельзя после закрытия присваивать одному и тому же процессу, а стороннему можно? или что это значит вообще?

Comment: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14388706/4827341), [2](https://habrahabr.ru/post/173415/) и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, благодарствую